# PyQt5 Hover over QPushButton with mouse pressed down

Tags: qt, pyqt5

I am trying to simulate a paint brush with Qt buttons instead of pixels. I have overloaded the event filter on each button and can detect eventHover or eventFilter only when the mouse is not pressed down. I want to hold mouse click down and detect if i collide with a button. Any suggestions as to what i should do from here?

```
def eventFilter(self, a0, a1):
    if a1.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Enter:
        if(self.mouse.pressed):
            ui_logic.square_press(self,"red")
    return super().eventFilter(a0, a1)

def square_press(button,color):
    style = "QPushButton{background-color:" + color + "}"
    button.setStyleSheet(style)
```

Thank you

Comment: maybe check to see if the button is pressed down? https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractbutton.html#pressed

Comment: down : bool
This property holds whether the button is pressed down

If this property is true, the button is pressed down. The signals pressed() and clicked() are not emitted if you set this property to true. The default is false.

Access functions:

bool isDown() const
void setDown(bool)

Comment: It doesn't really matter if the button is pressed down... Buttons don't read hover once the mouse is being held down. This is intended behavior and i know what i am trying to do is not the way to go but i am still looking for a work around. Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 0):

What i ended up doing is tracking the mouse and getting the widget at a location.
Example code:

```
class TrackMouse(QtWidgets.QWidget):
pressed = False
def __init__(self,obj,app):
    self.app = app
    super(QtWidgets.QWidget, self).__init__()
def eventFilter(self, a0, event):
    if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseMove:
        if(event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton):
            widget = self.app.widgetAt(event.globalPos())
            print(widget.__class__)
            if(widget.__class__ is CustomButtom):
                ui_logic.square_press(widget,"red")
    return super().eventFilter(a0, event)
```